# Combine/Compress data into another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to make an event that runs an an interval I just don't know how to compress everyone's stuff down into one line across each day.

Currently I have a `maintenance_tasks` table where it stores the time spent on certain maintenance tasks logged by the employee. An employee may have multiple maintenance task in a day.

I am trying to create another table containing each employees name for each day (at 6 AM) together with total time spent on tasks per day .

Below is an example of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

my current event query looks like this:

```sql
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS fetch_24hr_data
    ON SCHEDULE
        EVERY 1 DAY
        STARTS( TIMESTAMP(CURRENT DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL 6 HOUR)
    DO
```

Comment: Not clear what you are having a problem with? Is it the start time? or the query to retrieve the required data?

Comment: I'm trying to basically compress everyone's data down and send it to a a different table. As show above in the image, it's taking John Doe's name and adding his time spent to the new table under hours logged. Similarly with Fred Smith, and his older entry. I need to query this information but I dont know how to do this with everyone. There are 20+ employees and I need a way to do this to everyone through a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want that result this should do it for you. You will need to do a little research on `GROUP BY` to understand whats going on here

```
SELECT DATE(TIMESTAMP) as DATE, name, SUM(`TIME SPENT`) as `TOTAL HOURS LOGGED`
FROM `SINGULAR TASK TABLE`
GROUP BY DATE(TIMESTAMP), name
ORDER BY name;
```